# Temporarily disable null constraint in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with scripts that include changes to a database that can make the database to be in an invalid state temporarily. Currently I disable all constraints at the beginning and then reenabled them at the end of the script with the following code:

```
/*** Disable all constraints ***/
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
/*** Enable all constraints ***/
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

But this does not disable null constraints, as I understand from what I have read is that null constraints are treated differently than FK constraints.

I think it will be necessary to alter all tables to make them allow null and then alter them back again at the end of the script.

I cannot "hardcode" the name of the tables since I dont have that information, so I cannot do a lot of statements like:

```
ALTER TABLE someTable ALTER COLUMN someColumn INT NULL
```

It needs to be dynamic. Any ideas of how can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**
One scenario that I cannot handle is adding a new not null column to an existing table. I do not have control on the script that add this column (it is created by an automated tool), the script created is `ALTER TABLE someTable ADD someColumn INT NOT NULL`, after this statement some deletes/inserts/updates occur that make `someTable` to be in a valid state, but the error happens on the `ALTER` statement

Comment: Would it not be better to build the correct representation in staging tables, then transfer it into the real tables once it already satisfies the constraints?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE someTable ADD someColumn INT NOT NULL` is *never* a valid script against a table containing any rows. And if you have *no* control over this script, it will always error.

Comment: I've been trying to find some way to tell SQL Server to ignore that check, just like FK constraint can be ignored with the scripts I mentioned, but if it is definitely not possible to ignore null constraints you can provide some link to the docs and I will accept your answer

Comment: You have constraints in your columns? Then you have to drop them first, and recreate after. I did that as well like I did on my answer below already.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script where I select all fields from type `text` to make it `varchar(max)`.
Your approach is similar, but you need to modify it to your use.

- change the SQL to find the correct c.xtype you need.
- modify the WHERE statement to your demands change the @sql_select to your demand.
- PRINT it to test, then if it is like you need, uncomment the EXEC.

My Code (for edit):

```
-- change all text to varchar(max)
DECLARE @sql_select NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @column_name VARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE local_column_update_cursor CURSOR FOR

SELECT c.name as column_name, o.name as table_name 
FROM dbo.syscolumns c, dbo.sysobjects o
WHERE c.xtype IN (35,99) -- text/ntext
  AND o.id = c.id
  AND OBJECTPROPERTY(o.id, N'IsUserTable') = 1

OPEN local_column_update_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM local_column_update_cursor
INTO @column_name, @table_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @sql_select = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @table_name + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + @column_name + ' VARCHAR(MAX)'
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql_select
PRINT @sql_select

FETCH NEXT FROM local_column_update_cursor
INTO @column_name, @table_name
END

DEALLOCATE local_column_update_cursor

GO
```

I might edit to complete it to your demand later if I get some more time.